# Sublime Text 3 Completions for jQuery

Tags: jquery, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 for HTML, JS & jQuery dev. I have the jQuery & HTML5 packages installed. I like the completion list feature but find some problems with it:

1) I type `$.`. At this point I want to see the completion list for functions on main jQuery object - the same list as if I opened Command Palette and typed `$.` (I often forget the name of the function I want to use, so the tab triggers are no good for me).

2) Similarly, when starting a line of jQuery like  `$('#id').` I want to see a completion list for jQuery selection/element-group functions.

3) When I start typing a line like `$.pars` it shows me the completions, eg `$.parseJSON()` . However if I hit return it means I get `$.$.parseJSON()`, because it doesn't remove the pre-existing `$.`.

Is there a solution to these problems?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever found an answer for this - I was just running into the same problem and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925927/how-to-add-jquery-to-sublime-text-2) here.  The basic gist is that it's 'part of' the javascript - so just select javascript or use a js file and your jQuery will be added.