# Jquery package for sublime text 2

Tags: jquery, sublimetext2

I've followed this StackOverflow question 
[How to add Jquery to Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925927/how-to-add-jquery-to-sublime-text-2)
and downloaded the jquery package successfully but when I checked its syntaxes, there is no jquery language in it.Don't know what's happening! 
Please help me! I really want to add jquery package in my sublime editor.

Comment: Hello! I did what you said but still having problem ... @dicentiu

Answer (score 1):

The answer you referenced states that the `javascript` syntax is used for `jquery`.

The packages they recommend are for `jquery` snippets, and do not include an additional syntax.  There is no need for an additional syntax, as [**jquery is a subset of javascript**](https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-vs-javascript/).

---

I installed [**jQuery**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/jQuery), and can confirm that the snippets work as intended.  Try opening your file with the `javascript` syntax, type `ajax`, and execute the given auto-completion.  It should expand into the relevant `jquery` snippet.

[image: Demo]

---

You can get a list of all available `jquery` snippets by using [**this method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033039/identify-sublime-text-3-snippet-source/37033619#37033619).

Comment: In ST2 the packages are not in `.sublime-package` files, they're actually in the `Packages` folder (imagine that!). So, to list the snippets, all you need to do is select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**, then look in the `jQuery` folder for `.sublime-snippet` files.